# Microphone doesnt work for dictation but works fine (tested in voice memos) in other apps

Tags: microphone, voice-dictation, closed-clamshell

I've been trying to add dictation into my workflows and it works fine using my macbook pro's (m2 max) internal mic. However when in clamshell mode, the dictation feature wont use an alternative audio source. Other apps (such as voice memos) can use a different audio source as expected.

Is this a bug?

edit: looks like it might be a software issue - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251255108?answerId=252428753022#252428753022